# Type Mismatch in my coding while doing do while function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a type mismatch on my code but I do not know what the problem is.
I think it has to do with the rework worksheet but I am just not sure. Am I doing something wrong? I'm new to excel vba so I don't know

```
Sub ending_test()

Z = 3
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Z, 2))
  y = 4
  Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Rework").Cells(y, 1))
    If Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Z, 2) = Worksheets("Rework").Cells(y, 3) And
       Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Z, 3) = Worksheets("Rework").Cells(y, 4) And
       Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Z, 4) = Worksheets("Rework").Cells(y, 6) 
    Then
      Worksheets("Rework").Cells(y, 12).ClearContents
      Worksheets("Rework").Cells(y, 12) = Worksheets("Raw data").Cells(2, 7)
    End If
    y = y + 1
  Loop

  Z = Z + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: First: it's easier to read/troubleshoot code if it's properly formatted. Second: which line is the error happening on?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you split a command into separate lines you have to indicate it by having " _" at the en of the line. Not sure if that is what is causing the error...

So for your if statement it would look like

```
If Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Z, 2) = Worksheets("Rework").Cells(y, 3) _
And Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Z, 3) = Worksheets("Rework").Cells(y, 4) _
And Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Z, 4) = Worksheets("Rework").Cells(y, 6) _
Then
```

If you provide sample data it would be great.